# What happens if one query contains duplicate joins?

Tags: sql

I have an application filter which can generate duplicate SQL queries to the result SQL like:

```
select * from articles 
inner join users on articles.users_id = users.id 
inner join users on articles.users_id = users.id 
where users.name like %xxx%
```

The question is if a database is able to handle these duplicates or not. What happened in the database if this query comes inside? If I should remove it from the result SQL or if I can leave it as is.

Comment: I have removed the conflicting dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used.

Comment: Expect an error. Each users table instance need its own alias.

Comment: It should be compatible with all dbs not one of them. I would like to know what happens in which database or if it is implemented in all of them.

Comment: Yes mysql throws this error. That true.

Comment: Portable SQL applications, that's a challenge. Stick to standard SQL as much as possible. Use https://developer.mimer.com/sql-2016-validator/ to check your syntax. But you also have to try all code on all products. https://dbfiddle.uk/ is useful to verify functionality.

Comment: Thank you. Yes it is package which should be installable on different systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `self join`.
A self join is a regular join, but the table is joined with itself.

##### Example

```
SELECT
    A.Id,
    A.FullName,
    A.ManagerId,
    B.FullName as ManagerName
FROM Employees A
JOIN Employees B
ON A.ManagerId = B.Id
```

A and B are different table aliases for the same table.

Comment: It's 2021, you should not be recommending 30-year-old ansi-92 joins.

Comment: "down is the new up"... :)) Anyway, i edited my answer for the 21th century.

Comment: Thanks. This is not my case but its good to remind it.

Answer (score 1):

The self join, as its name implies, joins a table to itself. To use a self join, the table must contain a column (call it X) that acts as the primary key and a different column (call it Y) that stores values that can be matched up with the values in Column X. The values of Columns X and Y do not have to be the same for any given row, and the value in Column Y may even be null.

Let’s take a look at an example. Consider the table **Employees**:

| Id | FullName | Salary | ManagerId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Smith | 10000 | 3 |
| 2 | Jane Anderson | 12000 | 3 |
| 3 | Tom Lanon | 15000 | 4 |
| 4 | Anne Connor | 20000 |  |
| 5 | Jeremy York | 9000 | 1 |

Each employee has his/her own Id, which is our “Column X.” For a given employee (i.e., row), the column ManagerId contains the Id of his or her manager; this is our “Column Y.” If we trace the employee-manager pairs in this table using these columns:

- The manager of the employee John Smith is the employee with Id 3,
  i.e., Tom Lanon.
- The manager of the employee Jane Anderson is the employee with Id 3,
  i.e., Tom Lanon.
- The manager of the employee Tom Lanon is the employee with Id 4,
  i.e., Anne Connor.
- The employee Anne Connor does not have a manager; her ManagerId is
  null.
- The manager of the employee Jeremy York is the employee with Id 1,
  i.e., John Smith.

This type of table structure is very common in hierarchies. Now, to show the name of the manager for each employee in the same row, we can run the following query:

```
SELECT
    employee.Id,
        employee.FullName,
        employee.ManagerId,
        manager.FullName as ManagerName
FROM Employees employee
JOIN Employees manager
ON employee.ManagerId = manager.Id
```

which returns the following result:

| Id | FullName | ManagerId | ManagerName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Smith | 3 | Tom Lanon |
| 2 | Jane Anderson | 3 | Tom Lanon |
| 3 | Tom Lanon | 4 | Anne Connor |
| 5 | Jeremy York | 1 | John Smith |

The query selects the columns Id, FullName, and ManagerId from the table aliased employee. It also selects the FullName column of the table aliased manager and designates this column as ManagerName. As a result, every employee who has a manager is output along with his/her manager’s ID and name.

In this query, the Employees table is joined with itself and has two different roles:

- Role 1: It stores the employee data (alias employee).
- Role 2: It stores the manager data (alias manager).

By doing so, we are essentially considering the two copies of the Employees table as if they are two distinct tables, one for the employees and another for the managers.

You can find more about the concept of the self join in our article "[An illustrated guide to the SQL self join](https://learnsql.com/blog/illustrated-guide-sql-self-join/)".

Comment: Yes I understand. This is not my case but good to remind it. PS try to write it shorter like BlackMath below. I was lost in it on line 5.